# socket.io connection problem with python server and javascript client

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, socket.io

I'm trying to setup a socket.io server in Python and a socket.io client in JavaScript.

I have found examples for JS clients talking to node servers and python clients talking to python servers - but no examples for a JS client talking to a python server.. So I'm trying to combine code from different examples.

The client (html file served by apache, hosted anywhere you want)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect',function() {
  console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
});

socket.on('msg',function(data) {
  console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
});

socket.on('disconnect',function() {
  console.log('The client has disconnected!');
});

// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function send(message) {
  socket.emit('msg',message);
};

</script>
```

The server:

```
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
# the index.html file hosted by eventlet is a dummy file
# it appears to be required to host some html file.. 
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

@sio.on('msg')
def message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

When running this setup I can see in the Python terminal how the client is trying to connect:

```
    disconnect  db71fa07154c45d4b6e6c80073d27e17
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 17:28:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqC39S&sid=4e1045977dd14223b0d2913752dd5cf1 HTTP/1.1" 400 233 0.000296
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 17:28:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqC39Z&sid=4e1045977dd14223b0d2913752dd5cf1 HTTP/1.1" 400 233 0.000201
    connect  8650c5c7f735492e84a6e8774a20b069
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 17:28:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqC3Q3 HTTP/1.1" 200 396 0.001240
    disconnect  8650c5c7f735492e84a6e8774a20b069
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 17:29:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqC3QC&sid=8650c5c7f735492e84a6e8774a20b069 HTTP/1.1" 400 233 60.005087
    (12281) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 46478)
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 17:29:23] "GET /socket.io/?
```

and in chrome i see the clients connection tries:

```
index.js:83 POST http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqDzXq&sid=d08f2f55533b43ea81bd2f98201de277 400 (BAD REQUEST)
    i.create @ index
    index.js:83 POST http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYqDzXz&sid=d08f2f55533b43ea81bd2f98201de277 400 (BAD REQUEST)
    i.create @ index.
    index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=f23be764110d44cda684e633a990e0d7' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

They seem to communicate - but something is wrong, so the connection is never fully established.

Comment: You just need to debug it a little more. A good first step would be to add try/catch in the client around connect and print the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I had two instances of the server running. One of them was fired as a background thread and just kept running, so I forgot about it... There was two servers listening on the same port, that's why the communication got messed up.

Now everything works - so this code can be used as a minimal working example of python-JS socket.io communication.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to the server from the JS Client script, you have to use emit instead of send.

```
// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function send(message) {
  socket.emit('msg',message);
};
```